# How to convert all keys in JSON response to uppercase?

Tags: java, json, jackson, key, pojo

For example I have the following json response :

```
{
    StaTuS:succees,
    LanGuaGes: {
          Key1: English,
          key2: Spanish,
          kEy3: Indian
    }
}
```

The response can have many nested elements. I want to know how we can code in such a way that all the keys can be converted to uppercase in my response so that it matches the naming convention I used in my POJO class.

Like this:

```
{
   STATUS:succees,
   LANGUAGES: {
          KEY1: English,
          KEY2: Spanish,
          KEY3: Indian
   }
}
```

Comment: You can write a regex to find all the words which end with a : and convert these to uppercase, but to do this properly you should use a JSON parser though this would change the format.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey is there any other way? like using JsonNode or ObjectNode? or any such nodes available in JSON/JACKSON lib.

Comment: If you are using a parser already I would would use that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom PropertyNamingStrategy:

```
public class UpperCaseStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

    @Override
    public String translate(String propertyName) {

        return propertyName.toUpperCase();
    }

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CustomNamingStrategy());
```

See [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturePropertyNamingStrategy) for reference.

As a note a lower case strategy is implemented in `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy` as follows:

```
/**
 * Simple strategy where external name simply only uses lower-case characters,
 * and no separators.
 * Conversion from internal name like "someOtherValue" would be into external name
 * if "someothervalue".
 * 
 * @since 2.4
 */
public static class LowerCaseStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategyBase
{
    @Override
    public String translate(String input) {
        return input.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the problem is I can receive the json response from client in any format (Uppercase, lower case , capitalize each word). The answer you posted will convert the naming strategy in my POJO classes to any one format. But I want to convert the json response to match my POJO class naming strategy. I hope you got my point here. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but in case it helps.

```
public JsonArray jsonKeysUpper(JsonArray arr) {
    JsonArray aux = new JsonArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
        aux.add(jsonKeysUpper(arr.get(i).getAsJsonObject()));
    return aux;
}

public JsonObject jsonKeysUpper(JsonObject obj) {
    JsonObject aux = new JsonObject();
    if(obj.isJsonPrimitive()) return obj;
    if(obj.isJsonNull()) return null;
    // Iterate all properties
    for(String o : obj.keySet()) {
        if(obj.get(o).isJsonPrimitive())
            aux.addProperty(o.toUpperCase(), obj.get(o).getAsString());
        else if(obj.get(o).isJsonArray())
            aux.add(o.toUpperCase(), jsonKeysUpper(obj.get(o).getAsJsonArray()));
        else
            aux.add(o.toUpperCase(), jsonKeysUpper(obj.get(o).getAsJsonObject()));
    }
    return aux;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to convert your json to Upper case String keys json

```
ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE); 
obj.convertValue(jsonString, Map.class);
```